# Weird "Login failed for user 'sa': in Event viewer

Tags: sql-server, event-viewer

I'm hosting my web application on an **azure VM.** I've created a new user for `MSSQLSERVER` which my application can use to access the remote SQL server on that machine (so i do not use the sa user in my application). I have no problems at all accessing it, but i accidentally opened the Event Viewer and I found that each time I log into my application I get tens of messages that say

> "Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while
>   evaluating the password. [client: ......]

I first thought that it was an intruder, but then I realized that this message appears once I login to my application.

Why could this message be shown ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a state 1 issue, password validation gets done all-right, the problem is it is disabled for that user, in this case your MSSQLSERVER user or sa.
Try logging in with sa, and log out to refresh credentials . grant all permissions to new user that you created, and log in with your newly created user. This should solve the problem [make sure that error number is either of 18470 or 18456].

Comment: confirm once that your application is sending cached credentials, and the recent user creation has forced  it to send a log of these details regularly

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll try that out. Just one question, what do u mean by "state 1 issue" ?

Comment: @user4612290, https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/troubleshooting-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-login-failed-user/